# Escape single quotes inside script tag php

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, php-5.6

I have the following:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">(function(d) {var url="http://myurl.com"; var iframe = d.createElement("iframe");(iframe.frameElement || iframe).style.cssText = "width: 0; height: 0;border: 0;"; iframe.src = "javascript:false"; d.body.appendChild(iframe);var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document; doc.open().write(\'<body onload="window.location.href=\'+url+\'">\'); doc.close();})(document); </script>'; ?>
```

Which creates and iframe on a page and set the onload property of body tag of the iframe to the value of **url** variable.

The problem I have is this that I want the value of the url to be surrounded by single quotes like:

```
<body onload="window.location.href='http://myurl.com'"></body> (**Noticed the single quotes around the url?**)
```

But instead I got:

```
<body onload="window.location.href=http://myurl.com"></body> (**without single quotes around the url**)
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt that's possible that way. I'd try to echo in double quotes, escape those; keep the single for `doc.open().write('` and escape the single ones inside there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(d){
    var url='http://myurl.com'; 
    var iframe = d.createElement('iframe');
    (iframe.frameElement || iframe).style.cssText = 'width: 0; height: 0;border: 0;'; 
    iframe.src = 'javascript:false'; 
    d.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document; 
    doc.open().write('<body onload=\"window.location.href=\''+url+'\'\">'); 
    doc.close();
})(document); 
</script>";
 ?>
```

The main error is in the way that you're scaping the single quote.

Because you're trying to get the href value you need to scape first and concatenate, is easier if you use double quote to manage the strings inside PHP. In this way the onload function can be load using \" , and for get the url value just do \' inside the main string.

Also don't worry if you split the Javascript in more lines, that will be do easier identify the errors.

Comment: _"Try this"_ answers usually help a lot more if there is an explenation why this version _could_ help and what the essential difference is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jeff

Answer (score 2):

I would use a HEREDOC, personally.  They aren't that well known but they are very powerful way of doing strings

```
<?php
        echo <<<CODE 
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d) {var url="http://myurl.com"; var iframe = d.createElement("iframe");(iframe.frameElement || iframe).style.cssText = "width: 0; height: 0;border: 0;"; iframe.src = "javascript:false"; d.body.appendChild(iframe);var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document; doc.open().write('<body onload="window.location.href=\''+url+'\'">'); doc.close();})(document); </script>

CODE; //<-- note nothing can come before or after this no spaces or even this comment.
```

AS I put in the code **nothing can come before/after the ending Identifier** ( `SCRIPT` in this case) not even a single space or it wont work.  Except the `;` you can actually leave that out when putting it in an array, but that's a story for another day.

The Identifier can be anything but it should not appear in the text is a good general rule.

The advantage here is we are not using a quote or single quote to mark this as a string so it frees us up to use both. There is no need to escape them with this, outside of the normal use (no need for PHP's purposes)

The HEREDOC (above) works like `"` as far as variable interpolation ( replaces variables with their value).

The NOWDOC version works like `'` where it does not replace variables.  that is done like this

```
 <?php
 <<<'TAG'
 SOME CONTENT
 TAG;
```

Notice the `<<<'TAG'` instead of `<<<TAG`. The same rules apply as I mentioned above for the ending "tag". This is very very very important, which is why I made it bold and mentioned it 3 times.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, if you want extra `'` around the url, you will have to escape them, but this is for Javascripts purposes, not PHP.  Overall it still makes the code easier to deal with.

```
.write('<body onload="window.location.href=\''+url+'\'">');
```

Because there is no way around having to escape that for Javascript, but you don't have to worry about additional escaping due to PHP.  I'm pretty sure without the HEREDOC you would need to add 2 additional `\` to it like this `href=\\\''+url+'\\\'` which is pretty ugly, Or change your double quotes to `'` which I really don't like tags with single quotes (its a pet peeve of mine)  `<script type='text/javascript' ...`  it's just ugly to me.

Comment: I think this would still require additional `\'`  here `'...location.href=\''+url+'\'">'`

Comment: Only if it's required in the Javascript.

Comment: yes. the OP stated that he wanted/needs the `'` around the url.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it, it was really hard as this is a very long complicated string.